# Changing sys.stdin mode

Tags: python, stdin, sys, line-endings

How do I change the mode `stdin` is opened in? Specifically, we're piping CSV files to the python script to clean up the data, but with vertical tabs in the data it seems to need to be in universal-newlines mode.

The problem data seems to be some `\x0b` characters in the input stream. [edit: but actually turns out to be lines ending only with `\r`]

As printed by python, after opening one of the files with 'rU'

```
['P', 'B', '', '1 W Avene, #8\x0bMiami Beach, FL 33139']
['S', 'H', '\x0bElberon, NJ 07740', '9 E Avenue\x0bElberon, NJ 07740']
['C', 'W', 'E R A', '2 B 3rd Floor \x0bNew York NY 10023 ']
['D', 'M', '', '1 K Street, NW\x0bWashington, DC 20005']
['E', 'W', '', '5 P C Lane\x0bDenver, CO 80209-3311']
```

Comment: `\x0b` is not a newline. `rU` will not help.

Comment: 'rU' does solve the issue when opening one of the CSV files with the builtin `open()`. Edited the Q to refer to '\x0b' correctly.

Comment: Eh? You've still got `\x0b` in the input. So how can that be the problem? Why don't you show a hexdump of a problematic file or something?

Comment: That is a very good question, and I have no answer. I can only tell you that when `open`ing with `'r'`, the csv reader throws `"_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?"` and when opening the file with `'rU'` the csv readers behaves as expected.

Comment: Hexdump the file and post (part of) it.

Comment: http://pastie.org/7154345

Comment: As it turns out, the problem is that the file uses `'\r'` (CR, a.k.a. "classic mac" newlines) exclusively as the line terminator, rather than the more common LF or CRLF. It has nothing to do with the `\x0b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the CSV file you are reading uses CR (`\r`) newlines exclusively; it has nothing to do with the vertical tabs. Python 2.x opens `stdin` without universal line support (so that binary files work correctly).

As a workaround, you can try this, assuming your input is relatively small:

```
csv.reader(sys.stdin.read().split('\r'))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [PEP 278](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) universal-newlines is on by default.

> Universal newline support is enabled by default, but can be disabled during the configure of Python.

Do you have any sample data?

Comment: `stdin` is deliberately not opened using universal newline mode, so that binary files can be operated on.